# Active Admin Batch Dropdown Disabled Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am using the stable release `0.6.0` of Active Admin and rails `3.2.17`.
I am trying to get batch actions running, but I get this error in general when using active admin:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined 

active_admin.js:407 Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined
```

So the dropdown of batch actions will stay disabled.

My `active_admin.js` file looks like this:

```
//= require active_admin/base
```

If anyone knows why this isn't working I am really thankful!

Comment: I posted this problem at the official github site, too for further details https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4198

Comment: How did you define your `batch_action`?

Comment: The problem is not with the `batch action`. I have one `rails 4` instance and it works. But `active admin on 0.6` will always cause this problem on `rails 3.2`, whenever I click any page with tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug of ActiveAdmin you can choose 1 those options to fix it:

1. update your Gemfile to get the fix:

   ```
   gem 'activeadmin', '~> 0.6.6'
   ```
2. the second option is to override the CoffeeScript function with the changes in this commit https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3776/files